# this page is not working - Docker

Tags: django, docker

I have a local docker image running with a django project that i am running. The docker image is up but when i go to the local host with port 8000 which is set, gives a message that `the page is not working` and that `127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data`.

Here is the docker code:

```
omars-mbp:Split omarjandali$ docker build -t split .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  222.2kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3
 ---> 79e1dc9af1c1
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR user
 ---> 15e014da5b80
Removing intermediate container f4081817276f
Step 3/7 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> 1f444390862b
Step 4/7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in f75a6674ade2
 ---> 7641865ffc85
Removing intermediate container f75a6674ade2
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 40738a20f481
Collecting Django==1.11.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
Collecting gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
Collecting pytz (from Django==1.11.5->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django, gunicorn
Successfully installed Django-1.11.5 gunicorn-19.6.0 pytz-2017.3
 ---> 371a95617f78
Removing intermediate container 40738a20f481
Step 6/7 : COPY . .
 ---> fa31f9520063
Step 7/7 : CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
 ---> Running in 28b6a097dac4
 ---> c0d19bca8c2d
Removing intermediate container 28b6a097dac4
Successfully built c0d19bca8c2d
Successfully tagged split:latest
omars-mbp:Split omarjandali$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 split
d70035b14ab0c2046f2bfc8418960a0b1e5dd8bb75e09a045b41e94bcb097aa4
omars-mbp:Split omarjandali$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d70035b14ab0        split               "python manage.py ..."   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   focused_shirley
```

docker file:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR user
COPY requirements.txt ./
EXPOSE 8000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: can you please paste the Dockerfile here

Comment: updated post with docker file @NakulNarayanan

Comment: Did you start your image with option `-p 8000:8000` ?

Comment: yes you can see that at the bottom of the big chunk of code representing my docker commands

Comment: coudl it be the application and not the image running... idk I have never seen a message like this before...how is no data being sent.... @Munchkin

Comment: How do you run your image? Please show the full command (sth. like `docker run -p 8000:8000 split:latest`

Comment: `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 split` it is all above towards the bottom of the large chunk of code at the top of the post @Munchkin

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't saw that. can you `docker exec focused_shirley ping localhost:8000` ? where *focused_shirley* is the current name of your container, to be seen at `docker ps`

Comment: So i ran that line that you posted in the last step and I got `ping: unknown host`. so I set the port but there is no connection... @Munchkin

Comment: Run docker log [container]